# Почему не работает innerText и не только

Tags: javascript

При клике на `Pencil` дожлно появится текст в `input-e`. Но не происходит, в чем проблема? с innerHTML тоже пробовал

```js
    
    let inputS  = document.querySelector('.desc-s');
let pen = document.querySelectorAll(".pen-one")
let specs = document.querySelectorAll(".th-of-ec")
for(l=0;l<pen.length;l++){
    pen[l].onclick = () =>{
        inputS.value = specs[l].innerText
    }
}
```

```html
<i class="pen-one" aria-hidden="true">Pencil</i>
                    <p class = "th-of-ec">Theory of economics</p>
          <input type = "text" class = "desc-s">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы забыли добавить `let` к декларации `l`. Без этого в строгом режиме будет ошибка, а в несторогом создаётся переменная типа `var`, котораяя не будеет иметь привязки к итерации цикла и в вашеем обработчике после цикла будет содержать число, выходящее за границы массива (в примере это буте `1`), поэтому `specs[l].innerText` не будет найдено. Нужно вот так:

```js
let inputS  = document.querySelector('.desc-s');
let pen = document.querySelectorAll(".pen-one");
let specs = document.querySelectorAll(".th-of-ec");
for(let l = 0; l < pen.length; l++){
    pen[l].onclick = () => {
        inputS.value = specs[l].innerText;
    }
}
```

```html
<i class="pen-one" aria-hidden="true">Pencil</i>
<p class = "th-of-ec">Theory of economics</p>
<input type = "text" class = "desc-s">
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас в цикле происходит назначение функции клика, при этом в самом клике вы используете переменную  цикла `l`. Дело в том, что вы рассчитываете, что `l` в вашем примере будет равно 0, при исполнении кода `spec[l].innerText`. Однако на деле вы присваиваете не константное значение переменной `l`, а ссылку на данную переменную. Когда цикл заканчивается `l` становится равным 1 т.к. за телом цикла выполнится код `++l и l<pen.length`.

Таким образом в момент нажатия (исполнения функции, которую вы присвоили на клик), вы пытаетесь взять 1ый элемент массив `specs`, но у `specs` только один элемент с нулевым индексом.

```
inputS.value = specs[1].innerText
```

Скорее всего вы предполагали такое исполнение:

```js
    
let inputS  = document.querySelector('.desc-s');
let pen = document.querySelectorAll(".pen-one")
let specs = document.querySelectorAll(".th-of-ec")
for(l=0;l<pen.length;l++){
    pen[l].onclick = () =>{
        inputS.value = specs[0].innerText
    }
}
```

```html
<i class="pen-one" aria-hidden="true">Pencil</i>
<p class = "th-of-ec">Theory of economics</p>
<input type = "text" class = "desc-s">
```